# Bash script to source a Python virtual environment

Tags: bash, python

When loading a python virtual environment I need to run:

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

I want an alias for this command because I have to run it all the time. So I put the following in a file called "load.sh":

```
#!/bin/bash
source venv/bin/activate
```

And ran

```
chmod +x load.sh
```

However, now when I run ./load.sh there is no effect. My *suspicion* is that the word "source" may be the issue. But I don't know. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `source venv/bin/activate` commands modifies `load.sh`'s environment. When `load.sh` ends, this environment is forgotten. Also, it will only work if you're in the `$HOME` directory.

I think what you really want is to add to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias venv="source $HOME/venv/bin/activate"
```

then

```
venv
```

will do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is using virtualenvwrapper.

You can install it using `pip install virtualenvwrapper` (use `pip3` for Python3).
After that, add the following lines to the end the `.bashrc` file:

```
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
source ~/.local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
export WORKON_HOME=~/.virtualenvs
export PIP_VIRTUALENV_BASE=~/.virtualenvs
export PIP3_VIRTUALENV_BASE=~/.virtualenvs
```

Save and exit then you have to reload `.bashrc` by running `source ~/.bashrc` (just for once).
After that, whenever you want to create an env, run `mkvirtualenv <your_env_name>`.
And if you want to work on an env or to switch between envs, run `workon <env_name>`.
If you want to deactivate an env, run `deactivate`.

Comment: Ah, this is also a good alternative, thank you.